# "Tag too long" error tooltip shows up erroneously after canceling out of an edit

Tags: bug, tags, edits, editor

Steps to reproduce:

1. Edit a question.
2. Create a tag longer than 25 characters.
3. Cancel the edit.

Expected behavior:

The editor closes, nothing else happens.

Actual behavior:

An error tooltip appears alerting the user that they cannot add a tag longer than 25 characters.

> [image: Really long tag]
>
> [image: Error tooltip]

Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 (15G1212)

Google Chrome Version 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit)

Comment: Repro on Firefox, although not consistently, looks like you have to wait for the loading indicator but cancel before the text is converted to an actual tag. No repro on Chrome, but I don't get the error message at all there unless I hit "Save Edits".

Comment: @Cai I repro'd on Chrome, I'll add my browser and computer info.  What version of FF were you using?

Comment: FF 50.1.0 & Chrome  55.0.2883.95 both on MacOS